Environment Variables not available on page refresh in Gatsby app
I have a ReCaptcha (react-google-recaptcha) that will show when I go to the page via a link or navigate to the page inside of the React app but the ReCaptcha disappears if I do a F5 refresh on the form page with the ReCaptcha. It seems to be because the environment variables I am pulling into the useEffect() are null whenever I refresh the page.
We need our app to be build agnostic, so like the app itself shouldn't care what env it's being deployed in. So using something like dotenv isn't a solution we can use.
./userForm.tsx

const UserForm: FC<UserForm> = ({hostname, endpoint}) => {
  const {
    control,
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: {errors},
  } = useForm();
  const recaptchaRef = React.useRef<ReCAPTCHA | null>();
  const reCaptchaElement: any = useRef<any>(null);

  const [siteKey, setSiteKey] = useState<string | any>(null);
  const [recaptchaValidated, setRecaptchaValidated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    recaptchaRef.current?.reset();

    const isBrowser = () => typeof window !== "undefined";
    if (isBrowser()) {
      setSiteKey(window?.__RUNTIME_CONFIG__?.GATSBY_AMVER_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        <ReCAPTCHA 
          ref={reCaptchaElement}
          sitekey={siteKey} 
          onChange={handleRecaptcha}
        />
        <Button
        sx={{margin: '8px'}}
        onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        type="submit"
        disabled={!recaptchaValidated}
        size="small"
        variant="contained"
      >
        Submit Request
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserForm;

